# jQuery POST multidimensional form array

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form that collects the data from all it's inputs as a multidimensional array, and using the standard form submit function, this loads the target page and the PHP script reads the multidimensional array perfectly and results in the desired output.

```
<form action="target.php" method="post">

<?php foreach ($days as $day) { ?>

    <select name="roster[<?php echo $day->date() ?>][1]"> ... </select>
    <select name="roster[<?php echo $day->date() ?>][2]"> ... </select>
    <select name="roster[<?php echo $day->date() ?>][3]"> ... </select>

<?php } ?>

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

In the target PHP file, I just pick this up on `$_REQUEST['roster']`, then I can just work with it as a normal PHP array. Simple as can be.

However, I would like to convert this to an AJAX request using jQuery. I have read a few suggestions that say to pick up the form data using `$('form').serialize()` or `$('form').serializeArray()`, but this does not read the array correctly, and produces some strange output.

I am currently playing around with other suggestions which essentially involve traversing the DOM and constructing a new javascript array or object from the element data, then sending this via `$.ajax()`, but it all seems needlessly complex.

My question is: Is there a simple way of sending this form array data through jQuery and `$.ajax()`?

In all likelihood there is, and it will be bleeding obvious, but at the moment I can't see it!

EDIT:

Here is a `print_r` output of `$_REQUEST['roster']` from the standard form submit function:
(prettied up with `<pre>` formatting for readability):

```
Array
(
[2013-04-06] => Array
    (
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 7
    )

[2013-04-13] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 7
    )

[2013-04-20] => Array
    (
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 17
        [3] => 7
    )

[2013-04-27] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 7
    )

)
```

And here is the output for `$('form').serialize()`:

`roster%5B2013-04-06%5D%5B1%5D=8&roster%5B2013-04-06%5D%5B2%5D=3&roster%5B2013-04-06%5D%5B3%5D=7&roster%5B2013-04-13%5D%5B1%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-13%5D%5B2%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-13%5D%5B3%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-20%5D%5B1%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-20%5D%5B2%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-20%5D%5B3%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-27%5D%5B1%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-27%5D%5B2%5D=0&roster%5B2013-04-27%5D%5B3%5D=0`

And the output for `$('form').serializeArray()`:

`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Which if I then extract the data from each `[object Object]` using

```
$.each(data, function(index1, value1) {
    $.each(value1, function(index2, value2) {
        $('body').append('index1: '+index1+' value1: '+value1+' { index2: '+index2+' value2: '+value2+' }');
    });
});
```

I get:

```
index1: 0 value1: [object Object] { index2: name  value2: roster[2013-04-06][1] }
index1: 0 value1: [object Object] { index2: value value2: 8 }
index1: 1 value1: [object Object] { index2: name  value2: roster[2013-04-06][2] }
index1: 1 value1: [object Object] { index2: value value2: 3 }
```

...etc... for each input.

Obviously, from the `$.each` output, I should be able to access the data as object.name and object.value, then format everything into a new array to make it work with my PHP script, but is this the way to do it? or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have the code of generated HTML? Let us know the output of `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: This is the `var_dump` from the standard submit function that works: array(1) { ["roster"]=> array(4) { ["2013-04-06"]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "8" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "7" } ["2013-04-13"]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" } ["2013-04-20"]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" } ["2013-04-27"]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" } } }            ... or did you want to see the output of `.serializeArray()`?

Comment: Please update it in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.
```

That means that it will replace the `[` and `]` with `%5B` and `%5D`. 
Since it's a text string, a method would be to replace them back.

Example

```
var ser = $('#id').serialize();

ser = ser.replace(/%5B/g,"[");
ser = ser.replace(/%5D/g,"]");
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zfAe/2/)

Answer (score 0):

More simpler would be to use jQuerys $.param() function. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/